# I want to get an information about cell i interact with

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOR2b.png

I have a controller with settings and a table with custom cells. User will choose what sources he wants to be displayed so i need an information about switches in order to save it in User Defaults. I've created a method

```
- (IBAction)sourceSwitcherValueChanged:(id)sender {
if ([sender isOn]) {
    [[CSDMainManager sharedManager].userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:(???)]
}else{
    [[CSDMainManager sharedManager].userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:(???)]
}
```

}

I don't know how to extract a data from a cell, where you have changed a value of a switcher, or just to know what title it has. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a data set that is distributed among multiple components (cells) it would be most logical for the data source object to actually contain those data.

That means the data source is responsible to create the cells for the table view and will set the cell state depending on the data it caries as well. If the cell state then changes (switch pressed) the cell should report back to the data source. A custom delegate implementation on the cells should do the trick.

For instance if you have a view controller containing a table view with custom cells:

- Have the controller be the data source for the table view
- Have the controller include all data (settings) parameters
- Create a delegate containing the methods needed to modify the settings and implement those methods into the view controller
- Assign a delegate to every cell you create
- Call the delegate in cells when state changes

Since in cases as is your own it seems an overkill to create a delegate with a method for every setting I rather create an owner then a delegate. The difference is you pass the object itself as in `cell.owner = self` where owner is a weak property of the cell and is the same type as the controller. Now a controller may have a public properties or methods which expose the data or methods to modify the data.